# split a string by comma but ignore commas within single-quotes and inner single quote

Tags: c#

```
String myStr = "hai, 'how,are','you.','Local's'"; 

String[] valueList = Regex.Split(myStr , ",(?=(?:[^\']*\'[^\']*\')*(?![^\']*\')");
```

Without single quote after "l" in 'Locals' the above regex works.
But how do I escape the single Quote in 'Local's'?

Comment: might be a _perfect_ use case for using one of the many already existing implementations to parse CSV?

Comment: @CaiusJard. I am trying to split a string value with comma as delimiter. But the above regex wont split correctly with comma delimiter  when there is  Single Quote in 'Local's'

Answer (score 0):

I'd do some data cleanup before trying to parse it:

```
myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, @",\s+'", ",\"");
myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, @"'\s+,", "\",");
if(myStr.StartsWith("'"))
  myStr = '"' + myStr.Substring(1);
if(myStr.EndsWith("'"))
  myStr = myStr.Remove(myStr.Length - 1) +  '"';
```

This, or something like it - maybe you'll have more crazy data that defeats it and it'll need improving - will convert your string to a more typical `hai,"how,are","you.","Local's"`

Then run it through [some popular csv library](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Csv)